# I want call Unity funtion on android activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

```
public void CameraOnClick(){

    using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.d3d.viewer.NativePlugin")) {
        using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = javaClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("instance")) {
            Debug.Log ("Start Camera@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            //javaClass.CallStatic ("showCamera");
            currentActivity.Call("showCamera");
        }
}

}

public void getimageUrl1(string ImageUrl){
    imageurl1 = ImageUrl;
    Debug.Log ("ImageUrl11111111111111111111"+ImageUrl);
}
```

Android source

```
public class NativePlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {

    final Activity b = m_instance;

    final Activity a = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;

    private static NativePlugin m_instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("PlusPopupManager","getimageUrl1","22222");      //don't activate

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);



    }

    public static NativePlugin instance()
    {
        if(m_instance == null)
        {

            m_instance = new NativePlugin();
        }
        return m_instance;
    }



    public void showCamera ()     // Connect Camera
    {

        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("PlusPopupManager","getimageUrl1","111111");  //activate

        a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(a, NativePlugin.class);
               a.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("PlusPopupManager","getimageUrl1","333333");//don't activate


    }
}
```

manifast.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.d3d.viewer">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity android:name="com.d3d.viewer.NativePlugin"  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:launchMode="singleTask">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>



    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

</manifest>
```

I make ARR android plugins.and import Unity3d.

'UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage' is activated when I call 'showCamera'.
but don't activate when I call intent( NativePlugin) funtion.

why don't call 'UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage' funtion on android activity.

Comment: are you sure the GameObject with name PlusPopupManager is active at the moment when you call SendMessage? You need to be sure the GameObject is active at the moment you want to call a method on it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that GameObject is actived. How I can change source.

Comment: One way of doing that is to make a native call when the object is created and set a flag on the Android side. Next, each time you want to call showCamera from the Android side check to see if the flag is true, if it isn't then you don't make the call. You also need to change the flag back to false when the GameObject, on the Unity side, is destroyed.